# SciChart - ColumnRenderableSeries3D column diameter

Tags: scichart

I am trying to implement a chart with a `ColumnRenderableSeries3D` series, but with a small amount of data points (25x25) the columns are nearly invisible. At higher numbers of data points (100x100) with a wider range of values this problem becomes even worse and a Moiré pattern appears. What can be done to significantly increase the column's diameter, so they are easily seen and so the Moiré pattern disappears?

If it is relevant this is being rendered on a VM with a VMware ESXi 6.5 SVGA adapter on Windows Server 2016, over a RemoteDesktop connection. Surprisingly even though 3D support isnt enabled for the VM, `SciChart.Examples.Demo.exe` says DirectX hardware acceleration is enabled. The version of SciChart is 5.1.0.11405 and SharpDX is 4.0.1.

```
SciChart3DSurface SciChartSurface3d = new SciChart3DSurface();
XyzDataSeries3D<Double, Double, DateTime> MyXyzDataSeries = new XyzDataSeries3D<Double, Double, DateTime>();

SciChartSurface3d.XAxis = new NumericAxis3D();
SciChartSurface3d.YAxis = new NumericAxis3D();
SciChartSurface3d.ZAxis = new DateTimeAxis3D();
SciChartSurface3d.Camera = new Camera3D() { ZoomToFitOnAttach = true };
SciChartSurface3d.WorldDimensions = new Vector3(200, 100, 200);
SciChartSurface3d.RenderableSeries.Add(new ColumnRenderableSeries3D() { DataSeries= MyXyzDataSeries, ColumnShape = typeof(CubePointMarker3D),  DataPointWidthX = 1.0, Opacity = 1.0 });
SciChartSurface3d.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);`
SomeMethodToLoadTheDataSeries();
```

**25x25**
[image: 25x25]
**100x100**
[image: 100x100]

**Edit**

Changing `DataPointWidthX` to `DataPointWidth` doesn't help. With a width of 1.0:
[image]

Comment: Good question. DataPointWidth should do it. let me check & get back to you

Comment: Dr. ABT, nope DataPointWidth doesn't seem to help as you can see in my edit. Is there any way that I can manually change the column diameter perhaps via reflection or some other hacky means?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the problem by provided code sample. Please, report it [here](http://support.scichart.com/index.php?/Tickets/Submit). Add a package to the report which contains a small application that helps to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two modes of the column width definition:

- First and the default is called *MaxNonOverlapping*. In this mode, the maximum possible width is calculated where any column has enough space not to overlap others.
- Second is called *FixedSize*. In this mode, the width of a column is defined by a value from the *ColumnRenderableSeries3D.CoulmnFixedSize* property.

Definition of the mode is performed over the *ColumnRenderableSeries3D.ColumnSpacingMode* property. Below is the example how to setup fixed size column chart:

```
var renderableSeries3D = new ColumnRenderableSeries3D();
renderableSeries3D.ColumnSpacingMode = ColumnSpacingMode.FixedSize;
renderableSeries3D.CoulmnFixedSize = 25;
```

Note, a value of the CoulmnFixedSize property represents coordinates space. Thus it is related to the *SciChart3DSurface.WorldDimensions*. You can find more information about the coordinates space [here](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/v5.x/The%20SciChart3DSurface%20WorldDimensions%20Property.html).